# Run commands in parallel and wait for one group of commands to start before starting the next

Tags: shell-script, shell, background-process, process-management

I have created a script to run two threads in parallel using for loops.

```
for i in 1 2
do
echo "for loop in shell script iteration begins.." & done
```

As expected it runs in parallel, but I need to have an initial delay for the second thread to start while starting the threads parallelly.

Answer (score 2):

```
dodelay=0
for i in 1 2 ; do
  if [[ $dodelay -eq 1 ]] ; then
    sleep 10
  fi
  dodelay=1

  do-stuff-here $i
done
```

---

Alternatively, use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), it has a delay option:

> man parallel
>
> --delay mytime
>
> Delay starting next job by mytime. GNU parallel will pause mytime after starting each job. mytime is normally in seconds, but can
> be floats postfixed with s, m, h, or d which would multiply the float by 1, 60, 3600, or 86400. Thus these are equivalent: --delay
> 100000 and --delay 1d3.5h16.6m4s.

```
 parallel --delay 20 script-with-inner-for-loop.sh ::: 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the commands for each group in a subshell.  e.g.

```
for i in 1 2; do
  ( command1
    command2
    command3
    ...
  ) &
done
```

If you need an explicit delay between each group of background commands, use `sleep`.  e.g. for a delay of one second:

```
for i in 1 2; do
  ( command1
    command2
    command3
    ...
  ) &
  sleep 1
done
```